# Erro de sintaxe jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá estou tendo um problema quanto ao uso desse código. Quero que dentro da div com a class output mostre o seguinte código html, esse código está dentro de um *for* por isso usei o append, aqui está dando erro de sintaxe, vocês poderiam me ajudar?

```
 $('.output').append('<li class="canal row"><div class="col"><img style="width: 80px; height: 80px;" class="rounded-circle" src="'+data2.logo+'"></div> <div class="col-6"><p class="tituloCanal"><a href="'+data2.url+'" class="linkTitulo">'+data2.display_name+'</a> </p><p class="desc">'+data2.status+'</p> </div>'+
 if(data.stream===null){+'<div class="online col"> <a href="#" class="onlineIcon">on</a> </div>'+} else{'+<div class="online col"> <a href="#" class="onlineIcon">on</a> </div>'+}+'</li>');
```

Comment: Você está tentando concatenar um `if` na *string*?

Comment: Cara, tira esse _if_ de dentro do _append_. Coloca essa sua _string_ dentro de uma variável, manipula ela fora e por último, adiciona a variável no _append_.

Comment: isso mesmo! @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não podes usar `if/else` dentro de concatenação de strings dessa maneira.

Separa a parte do if/else e concatena só o resultado. Algo assim:

```js
var stream = data.stream === null ?
  '<div class="online col"> <a href="#" class="onlineIcon">on</a> </div>' :
  '<div class="online col"> <a href="#" class="onlineIcon">on</a> </div>';

$('.output').append(
  '<li class="canal row"><div class="col"><img style="width: 80px; height: 80px;" class="rounded-circle" src="' +
  data2.logo + '"></div> <div class="col-6"><p class="tituloCanal"><a href="' +
  data2.url + '" class="linkTitulo">' +
  data2.display_name + '</a> </p><p class="desc">' +
  data2.status + '</p> </div>' + 
  stream +
  '</li>'
);
```

Comment: Não sabia que não podia usar if e else em concatenação, achei a sua solução de colocar em uma variável com uma condição ternária bem organizada.

Answer (score 5):

Não dá pra usar o `if` deste jeito, você precisa de um operador ternário.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. Se a condição for `true` será concatenado o que vem depois do **`?`**, caso contrário, será concatenado o que vem depois de **`:`**.

Obviamente que dava pra organizar melhor o código e tratar isso fora, aliás, uma dica: dê uma organizada melhor no código.

De qualquer maneira, o problema mesmo é usar este `if-else` dentro da concatenação.

```
(data.stream === null
? '<div class="online col"> <a href="#" class="onlineIcon">on</a> </div>' 
: '<div class="online col"> <a href="#" class="onlineIcon">on</a> </div>' ) 
+ '</li>';
```